# Is a 100 amp transfer switch adequate for a 15KW generator?

Tags: electrical-panel

I want to add a 15KW standby generator to my 200 amp house The generator came with a 100amp transfer switch. Is this arrangement ok or should I get a 200 a transfer switch?

Comment: Doesn't really matter what breaker is on the service panel--it can only draw what the generator can provide anyway. We can assume that the manufacturer shipped a switch that's up to the task. I'll let someone with more expertise post a proper answer.

Comment: How is your transfer switch going to be installed? If the only load it needs to carry is the roughly 60A from the generator, 100A should be fine. But if the transfer switch handles the utility disconnect and is carrying that load as well, you need to size it for the service, not just the generator.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the transfer switch and your existing breaker panel(s)? It may be advantageous to use a circuit breaker interlock instead of the transfer switch. Also, are you looking for manual or automatic generator start and transfer operation?

Comment: 62.5 amps = 15KW @240V and most generators will not be kind to trying to overload one leg of 120V, so you have plenty of headroom on a 100A switch.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You said it much more succinctly than I did in my answer below. Really important how the xfer switch will be installed.

Comment: What are the models of the generator and transfer switch in question?  And are you hoping to back up everything in the house, or just a subset?

Comment: What are you trying to back up here, and what make and model is the transfer switch in question?

Comment: Will the 200A "utility mode" current be flowing through this switch?  Is this an automatic transfer switch (if so, please elaborate on the loads it will serve).  If it's a manual transfer switch, let us know your panel type and age, we may have a better answer.

Comment: We need more info on the transfer switch(s) if it is a whole house type no 100 amp is not enough because you need to be able to handle the house not the generator.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a 200A transfer switch will do you no good unless you're planning on buying a 48KW generator soon. Your transfer switch is suitable.  Your generator cannot produce 100A so you need to be watchful of what loads you switch on, careful that neither phase exceeds 62.5A and that the two phases are in balance within the limits in your generator documentation.   If you don't do that your generator can brown out or stall.

If you use the 100A transfer switch with 100A breakers you need to use a feed wire suitable for 100A between the generator, switch, and panel.   You could use the 100A transfer switch with 60A breakers, then you can use lighter feed wiring and you'll pop the breakers before browning out.  Even then you have to watch the balance of the phases.

Answer (score 0):

The 100 Amp transfer switch will be fine. Your generator will put out a maximum of 62.5 Amps at 240 Volt utilizing both legs and 62.5 amps at 120 Volts on each leg. You would be able to increase your generator size up to 24 KW+- before having to change out your transfer switch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no-one has asked yet how this will be installed!  Clearly it can't be put between the meter and a 200 amp service unless it the xfer switch was upgraded to 200 amps.   So that implies moving some circuits to a sub-panel and all that entails. at 15,000 watts, I'm assuming the xfer switch is automatic...not one of those silly expensive generac types with a power inlet and a bunch of breaker you have to manually choose to turn on...reminds me of the electrical supply of that old sitcom, "Green acres".

If the OP wants "whole house" backup, meaning EVERYTHING, the best choice is the xfer switch goes between the meter and the main panel. But that technically turns the main panel into a sub-panel (neutral isolated from ground). The xfer switch will also have to be rated for "service disconnect", meaning it must have it's own 200 amp breaker.

So, once again, as I hate to say: ***It depends.*** If the OP can live with the most important circuits moved to a sub-panel with the xfer switch between the main panel and the sub-panel, that might be the least expensive and most practical approach.   If not, the OP has to upgrade the xfer switch to 200A, has to  get the POCO to pull the meter, get an electrician to install the xfer switch in between the meter and main panel and make sure the previously main panel conforms to sub-panel code.

I'm probably answering more than the OP asked, but just wanted him/her to know all the pro/cons of their choice...not just if the xfer switch could handle the load.

Comment: Given that the transfer switch "came with" the generator, I would not be surprised if it is one of those silly manual generac ones.

Comment: @NateS.  Hard to tell. In my son's recent new house build, we got a 15,000 watt Kohler generator that came with a 200 amp automatic transfer switch and start up controls.  I wired it between the meter and the main panel.   Nice setup.   We need to hear more from the OP to give the best advice.